# rewrite function not to trigger ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am having trouble with @tf.function.

I am unsure of how to write this function without creating a variable, I think this would be the best solution but am very unsure of how to do so.

I would need to create a tensor object filled with zeros with 1s in a few specific spots and this I do not know how to do with out creating a numpy array or a tf.Variable.

I am trying to write a function that will map the output tensor from my network to integer values in a specific way, kinda like the softmax function. This function is called from another function which has the @tf.function tag so removing the tag for this small function is not an option.

```
@tf.function
def convert_action(self, action_logits_t: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
  self.res = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_actions, tf.int32))
  if action_logits_t[0][0] > 0.2:
    return self.res[0].assign(1)
  else:
    ccy1 = tf.math.argmax(action_logits_t[0][1:NUM_CCYS + 1])
    self.res = self.res[ccy1 + 1].assign(1) 
    ccy2 = tf.math.argmax(action_logits_t[0][NUM_CCYS + 1:2 * NUM_CCYS + 1])
    self.res = self.res[ccy2 + 1 + NUM_CCYS].assign(1)
    bucket = tf.math.argmax(action_logits_t[0][2 * NUM_CCYS + 1:])
    return self.res[bucket + 1 + 2 * NUM_CCYS].assign(1)
```

Comment: As far as I understand - you don't need `tf.Variable`. Are you using it just to assign to a specified element ?

Comment: I agree with @Andrey. What is your function returning? do you need to reset to zeros your "res" and that is why you are creating another variable with tf.Variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being able to use left side indexing and assignment is a bit painful, but there is some op to do what you want: [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd)

```
def convert_action(action_logits_t):
    if action_logits_t[0][0] > 0.2:
        return tf.one_hot([0], depth=num_actions)
    else:
        indexes = [
            tf.math.argmax(action_logits_t[0][1 : NUM_CCYS + 1]) + 1,
            tf.math.argmax(action_logits_t[0][NUM_CCYS + 1 : 2 * NUM_CCYS + 1])
            + 1
            + NUM_CCYS,
            tf.math.argmax(action_logits_t[0][2 * NUM_CCYS + 1 :]) + 1 + 2 * NUM_CCYS,
        ]
        return tf.scatter_nd(
            indices=tf.expand_dims(indexes, axis=-1),
            updates=tf.ones_like(indexes),
            shape=[num_actions],
        )
```

Or another, a bit creative with [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot?hl=en) and [`tf.reduce_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum):

```
def convert_action(action_logits_t):
    if action_logits_t[0][0] > 0.2:
        return tf.one_hot([0], depth=num_actions)
    else:
        indexes = [
            tf.math.argmax(action_logits_t[0][1:NUM_CCYS + 1]) + 1,
            tf.math.argmax(action_logits_t[0][NUM_CCYS + 1:2 * NUM_CCYS + 1]) + 1 + NUM_CCYS,
            tf.math.argmax(action_logits_t[0][2 * NUM_CCYS + 1:]) + 1 + 2 * NUM_CCYS
        ]
        return tf.reduce_sum(
            tf.one_hot(indexes, depth=num_actions), axis=0
        )
```